# SOAP API error anyType

Tags: soap-api

I have two salesforce accounts, source and destination. In source, I have a class which returns a list of accounts:

```
global class soapdemo1
{ webservice static List<Account> CreateAccount(string accName)
  //some code here to create multiple accounts
  //this class compiles successfully
}
```

In source, for soapdemo1 class, I generate the wsdl file and name it as generalwsdl.wsdl, and I create the partnerwsdl.wsdl file.

In destination, when I upload generalwsdl.wsdl, click parse, I get no errors. Now, when I click the generate apex code button, it says error: "Unsupported schema type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType".

I changed anyType to string, but now I get a different error: "Unable to find complexType for {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapDemo1}JunctionIdListNames"

Then, I change string to Account, but it results in same error as above.
I am at logger heads with this issue, so please advise me how to resolve this.